# Workaround for <video> loop attribute in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Does anyone know of a workaround (JavaScript, I'd guess) for looping HTML5 `<video>` elements in Firefox. The `loop` attribute isn't currently supported in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have any videos to test with but found a solution on the firefox support forums using jQuery that you can try out:

```
$("#yourID").bind('ended', function(){ 
  this.play();
});
```

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/747220

Comment: Does anything need to be done other than adding a jQuery import for that to work?

Comment: No, just import jQuery as usual, bind the id to the js line and add wherever you prefer (header, body) and it should work.

Comment: I have jQuery imported, and used Firebug to verify that it's actually there, but it isn't working. Code here: https://gist.github.com/1208975

Comment: just ran some test, its working fine for me, here is my full html with a test video from some site i found:   <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>  
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.  
 </video>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('video').bind('ended', function(){ 
   this.play();
 });
</script>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ah. I had the `<script>` inside the page `<head>`, not the `<body>`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I find that even doing this, sometimes there is a long delay before the video restarts (on the order of 30 seconds).  I am even using an objectDataUrl, so the video is available locally without hitting the network.

Answer (score 5):

Please do not abuse jQuery like this!!  You don't need a massive library to bind a simple listener!  Use this:

```
 document.getElementById('video').addEventListener("ended", function(){this.play();});
```

This will trigger when the video ends.  The anonymous function will then be ran.  "this" refers to the video element by which we execute the play function on causing the video to re-play.

Shame on Firefox for letting this bug go unfixed for so long!

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here worked for me with Firefox on OS X.

My solution was to add **loop="loop"** to the video tag. Omitting the ="loop" caused the video not to loop.

```
<video src="myvid.mp4" loop="loop"></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

A JQuery workaround as nabbed from Mozilla's site worked for me ( http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/747220 ):

```
$("#yourID").bind('ended', function(){
this.play();
});
```