# Loop HTML5 Videos on "ended" Event

Tags: jquery, html5-video

An html5 video plays. Once it has finished, the script below is called, which incriments to the next video which it adds to the next line and begins playing it. How do I turn this into a loop so once that second video finishes playing, it will append a third video, and so on?

```
<div>
    <video id="video0" autoplay>
        <source src="video0.mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

.

```
var i=0
$('video'+i).on("ended", function() {
    i++;
    $(this).parent().append('<br /><video id="video'
        + i
        + '" autoplay><source src="video'
        + i
        + '.mp4" /></video>');
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer:**

After re-reading your question and seeing the changes, here is some logic that should do what you're asking...

```
var i = 0;
var numVideos = 5;
var addVideo = function() {
    i++;
    var nextVideo=$('<video id="video'
        + i
        + '" autoplay><source src="video'
        + i
        + '.mp4" /></video>');
    nextVideo.on('ended', addVideo);
    $(this).after('<br />').after(nextVideo);
};
$('video0').on('ended', addVideo);
```

**Original Answer:**

How about adding the `loop` attribute to your `video` tag?  [W3 Resource](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. I'm not trying to loop the same video, I'm trying to create a video below it after the first has finished playing, and make it so after that second video has ended, a third video is created below it, and so on. I edited my original post to better reflect that.

Comment: I received a down vote, so I updated my answer based on the new criteria of the question.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 video can be looped by using the 'loop' attribute:

```
loop="loop"
```

Browsers without loop support can be supported via:

```
$("#video").bind('ended', function(){ 
  this.play();
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375088/workaround-for-video-loop-attribute-in-firefox)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. I'm not trying to loop the same video, I'm trying to create a video below it after the first has finished playing, and make it so after that second video has ended, a third video is created below it, and so on. I edited my original post to better reflect that.

Comment: In that case, you may wish to change the source of the existing video element to point to the new video, and then call `play()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it help you?

**In Head tag:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
            video_count = 1; 
            function run() { 
                video_count++; 
                var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo"); 
                if (video_count == 4) 
                    video_count = 1; 
                var nextVideo = "ModelVideo/1/video" + video_count + ".mp4"; 
                videoPlayer.src = nextVideo; 
                videoPlayer.load(); 
                videoPlayer.play();        
            }; 
        </script>
```

**In Body tag:**

```
    <div style="width: 30%;"> 
            <video id="homevideo" width="100%" controls autoplay onended="run()"> 
            <source id="ss" src="ModelVideo/1/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/></video> 
        </div>
```

Comment: anyone has more better way of achieving this functionality and also a more functionality for add of any message as like live  tv on bottom of video, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it help you for jQuery?

**In Head tag:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                v_count = 1;
                $("#video").bind('ended', function () {
                    v_count++;
                    if (v_count == 4)
                        v_count = 1;
                    $("#sovideo").attr("src", "ModelVideo/1/video" + v_count + ".mp4");
                    $("#video").load();
                    this.play();                            
            });   
        </script>
```

**In Body tag:**

```
        <div style="width: 30%;"> 
            <video id="video" width="100%" controls>
            <source id="sovideo" src="ModelVideo/1/video1.mp4" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Please learn to write grammatically understandable English before posting on this English Q/A site.